# Differentiating under the integral sign on a manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Given a smooth, compact, oriented manifold $M^1 $ with $\partial M=\emptyset$ , a 1-form $\lambda$ and the flow of a smooth vector field $\theta_t$  I have the function
$$t\mapsto \intop_M\theta_t^*\lambda$$
I want to differentiate with respect to $t$ under the integral sign. Now, by definition of integration on a manifold we have (with $\{f_\alpha\}_\alpha$ a partition of unity)
$$\intop_M\theta_t^*\lambda = \intop_M\lambda\circ\theta_t=\sum_{\alpha\in I} \intop _{\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)} f_\alpha\lambda_1(\theta_t(x))d(\theta_t(x))$$
And here is the pickle. I have $t$ appearing in the integration variable. So I would like to say that since the integrand is smooth I can just do (for fixed $\alpha$)
$$\frac d {dt} \intop _{\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)} f_\alpha\lambda_1(\theta_t(x))d(\theta_t(x)) = \intop _{\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)} f_\alpha \frac \partial {\partial t} \lambda_1(\theta_t(x))d(\theta_t(x))$$
and then regroup everything together to obtain
$$\intop_M \frac \partial {\partial t} \theta_t^*\lambda$$
which happens to be integration of the Lie derivative of $\theta_t^*\lambda$
The question is whether this is true and if so, why?

Comment: I expect some change of variable type formula to hold i.e. $dx(t) = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)dt$, whatever that means. This is done before the differentiation, and then you carry the derivative inside (via Lebesgue Lemma, probably).

Comment: I think the differentiability should be taken in the sense of banach space

Comment: It doesn't make sense to integrate a one form on $M$.

Comment: For integrating a $1$-form on a $1$-manifold, you really don't need to bring partitions of unity into the picture at all!  If the $1$-manifold is connected, it's either an interval or a circle. In either event, you can (essentially) globally parametrize it. At any rate, you can explicitly compute the Lie derivative of your $1$-form and integrate it.

Comment: @TedShifrin This is what i would like to do. The question is: why is differentiating the integral the same as integrating the derivative?

Comment: Because differentiating under the integral sign works fine with manifolds. Indeed, from my remark about global parametrization, it's really easy in your case — it's just the usual theorem about differentiating under the integral sign on $[a,b]$ or $\Bbb R$.